# Inserting rows per hour into another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, both have the same column structure. The first table has around 700 million rows. I want to copy these rows per hour into the second table.

To test my approach I've tried this query, which copies only one row from the first table into the second. The execution time for this query was around 4.5min

```sql
DECLARE @startDate DateTime2(0) = '2020-03-29 13:05:18'

DECLARE @endDate DateTime2(0) = '2020-03-29 13:05:18'

WHILE @startDate <= '2020-03-29 13:05:18'
BEGIN

SET @endDate = DATEADD(hh, 1, @startDate)

INSERT INTO "secondtable"

SELECT *
FROM "first table"
WHERE time_position >= @myCounter AND time_position <= '2020-03-29 13:05:18'

SET @startDate = DATEADD(hh, 1, @startDate)

END
```

For inserting rows per hour into the second table, I've tried this query but it's executing for 20+ minutes and the risk will probably run out of space and stop the query.

```sql
DECLARE @startTime DateTime2(0) = (select min(time_position) from "first table" where time_position = '2022-01-01')

DECLARE @endTime datetime2(0) = (select max(time_position) from "first table" where time_position = '2022-01-01')

WHILE @startTime <= @endTime 
BEGIN


INSERT INTO "second table"

SELECT *

FROM "first table"

WHERE time_position >= @startTime AND time_position <= @endTime

SET @startTime = DATEADD(HH, 1, @startTime)

END
```

How can I copy these rows per hour into the second table in an efficient way?

[image: first table]

[image: second table]

[image: execution plan]

Comment: Are you sure your bottleneck is copying and not the search for the rows in the first place? Have you looked at your execution plan to see where the bottleneck may be? Why would you run out of space? How big is the table in megabytes? Is the date column (`time_position`) indexed? Why do you want to insert them per hour?

Comment: There's around 1 million rows per day and a query with this amount of rows would take very long time to execute.
The column time_position is not indexed and I've checked the execution plan and it showed me this. (third pic)
The table's size is 391984,00 MB

Comment: Why are you looping?

Comment: I'm looping in order to insert the rows hourly

Comment: I'm not undrstanding your requirement - are you trying to copy the entire table per hour, or just rows inserted in the last hour, or rows changed in the last hour etc?

Comment: I'm trying to copy the entire table in small chunks "preferably per hour" into another table.

Comment: This is an ETL challenge. I suggest building an SSIS package, which is designed for this exactly. Bulk inserts like this are head-spinning fast. Another option is to create an SQL Agent Job to fire every hour and grab something like INSERT TOP 100 ROWS FROM SourceTable WHERE NOT EXISTS in DestinationTable

Comment: I've created a query and run it on a SSIS package and it worked thanks !